# C# Date String to different format WITHOUT converting to date first

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to convert date strings from one format to another without actually converting them to a date?

I need something like this:

```
string inputDateString = "01/01/2012 23:36:17.234";
string inputFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff";

string ouputFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff";
string outputDateString = StringDate.Convert(inputDateString,inputFormat, outputFormat);
```

I can obviously write a StringDate class to parse the formats, but that would seem like reinventing the wheel.  The reason I can't go first to a date is I have had numerous problems with timezones/server times, and don't have control over the environment in which this will run.  I just want to be 100% sure that the date string is just rearanged, and not messed up!

Thanks

**EDIT**
The output format will always be the same, however the input format could be any combination of:

Time variations:
HH:mm:ss.fff
HH:mm:ss
HH:mm

Date variations (could be more):
dd/MM/yyyy 
dd/MM/yy 
MM/dd/yyyy 
MM/dd/yy 
yyyy/MM/dd 
yy/MM/dd

Comment: Writing a general function to do this using different date formats is non-trivial. However, for a single known input and output format, it becomes straightforward (regex or substrings). What's it to be?

Comment: How about using UTC for all date-time operations, and than just representing it as client's datetime? If you absolutely sure you want it in such an unusual and corrupted way as you describe, why not using regexes?

Comment: @PaulGrimshaw: What pattern is that format using? Because it's not the .NET custom date/time format, unless you really want the month name after the seconds...

Comment: @JonSkeet Apologies, it should be the .NET custom date/time format, probably just made a mistake...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should *absolutely* parse it first. You just need to be careful about *how* you parse it and format it. Just because you've had problems with time zones in the past doesn't mean you should just avoid the parsing/formatting - it means you should work out what you want to do in terms of time zones. It *sounds* like you just want to treat the data as local. I suspect you'll want to specify `DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal` and also use the invariant culture.

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` with the *exact* format you're expecting (and a specific culture, probably the invariant culture), then call `ToString` with the output format and again, the relevant culture.

Also note that your expecting format string isn't correct - you're using `hh` when you mean `HH`, and I suspect you want `fff` instead of `mmm`. Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string inputDateString = "01/01/2012 23:36:17.234";
        string inputFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff";        
        string outputFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff";

        DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(inputDateString, inputFormat,
                                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                              DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
        string outputDateString = parsed.ToString(outputFormat, 
                                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(outputDateString); // Prints 2012/01/01 23:36:17.234
    }
}
```

You might also want to look into my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) project, which would allow you to create a `LocalDateTimePattern` for each of input and output, then reuse them  repeatedly.

Comment: This certainly looks like the way forward.  Thanks for the assistance.  It is the ParseExact that is the key, as before I've had problems with the date formats being "guessed" by the system.

Comment: @PaulGrimshaw: Absolutely - heuristics might be okay for user-entered data, but not for data where you know the right format already.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
string inputDateString = "01/01/2012 23:36:17.234";
string inputFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff";

string ouputFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff";

string outputDateString = DateTime.ParseExact(inputDateString, inputFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString(ouputFormat);
```

Comment: You should specify the culture on output as well. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score -3):

```
string s = System.Convert.ToDateTime(System.Convert.ToDateTime(inputDateString).ToString(inputFormat)).ToString(ouputFormat);
System.Console.Write(s);
```

Comment: Absolutely not. This is ignoring the input format when parsing, and then trying to use the output format *on a string*.